# How to redirect a request to a specific-route in laravel from jeffochoa tutorial

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to implement this example code by jeff ochoa which lets you redirect a request to a specific-route in laravel.

https://jeffochoa.me/redirect-a-request-to-a-specific-route-laravel

I'm getting this error when I run the code:

```
Got error 'PHP message: [31 /.../app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php 0 Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::App\\Providers\\{closure}() must be an instance of Request, instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request given]'
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? The $request object is already pre-defined as an Illuminate\Http\Request when it's received so is it possible to convert it or ??

Here's my current code...

I have added this route into /routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'API'],function() {
    Route::get('/test',"testAPIController@get");
    Route::get('macro.test', ['as' => 'macro.test', 'uses' => 'testAPIController0@get']);
});
```

I have added the Route::macro to /app/providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Route::macro(
            'sendToRoute',
            function (Request $request, string $routeName) {
                $route = tap($this->routes->getByName($routeName))->bind($request);
                $this->current = $route;
                return $this->runRoute($request, $this->current);
            }
        );

        parent::boot();
    }
```

The controller that's calling the macro:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use Route;

class testAPIController extends AppBaseController
{
    public function get(Request $request)
    {
        return Route::sendToRoute($request,"macro.test");
    }
}
?>
```

The target Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;

class testAPIController0 extends AppBaseController
{
    public function get(Request $request) {
        die("Hello World");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of macro function, you should register the `Illuminate\Http\Request` instead of only `Request`. Like this:

```php
/**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Route::macro(
            'sendToRoute',
            function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, string $routeName) {
                $route = tap($this->routes->getByName($routeName))->bind($request);
                $this->current = $route;
                return $this->runRoute($request, $this->current);
            }
        );

        parent::boot();
    }
```

Of course you can also import the `Illuminate\Http\Request` on top of php file

Comment: Saeid - you're a legend!!  haha that was so simple. I have been scratching my head all day trying different things. Thanks!! :)